# Getting value from JSON PHP

Tags: php, json, api, jsonresult

I am trying to get ID from this Json.

I have already tried many things such as:

- json_encode($array);
  and then trying to get value using
- $array->contact->id;
- $array['contact']['id];
  BUT FAILED.

This is the response I get from active campaign API. I am using PHP, and the only issue I am facing is extracting ID from this Response.

How can I get contact --> id from the response? Can somebody help?

here's the code:`

```
{
  "fieldValues": [
    {
      "contact": "113",
      "field": "1",
      "value": "The Value for First Field",
      "cdate": "2020-08-01T10:54:59-05:00",
      "udate": "2020-08-01T14:13:34-05:00",
      "links": {
        "owner": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/3/fieldValues/11797/owner",
        "field": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/3/fieldValues/11797/field"
      },
      "id": "11797",
      "owner": "113"
    },
    {
      "contact": "113",
      "field": "6",
      "value": "2008-01-20",
      "cdate": "2020-08-01T10:54:59-05:00",
      "udate": "2020-08-01T14:13:34-05:00",
      "links": {
        "owner": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/3/fieldValues/11798/owner",
        "field": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/3/fieldValues/11798/field"
      },
      "id": "11798",
      "owner": "113"
    }
  ],
  "contact": {
    "email": "johndoe@example.com",
    "cdate": "2018-09-28T13:50:41-05:00",
    "udate": "2018-09-28T13:50:41-05:00",
    "orgid": "",
    "links": {
      "bounceLogs": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/bounceLogs",
      "contactAutomations": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactAutomations",
      "contactData": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactData",
      "contactGoals": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactGoals",
      "contactLists": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactLists",
      "contactLogs": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactLogs",
      "contactTags": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactTags",
      "contactDeals": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/contactDeals",
      "deals": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/deals",
      "fieldValues": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/fieldValues",
      "geoIps": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/geoIps",
      "notes": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/notes",
      "organization": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/organization",
      "plusAppend": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/plusAppend",
      "trackingLogs": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/trackingLogs",
      "scoreValues": "https://:account.api-us1.com/api/:version/contacts/113/scoreValues"
    },
    "id": "113",
    "organization": ""
  }
}
```

`

Comment: You need to use `json_decode` and not encode.

Comment: $obj = json_decode($jsonStr);
echo $obj->contact->id;